# cleanup all UIComponents inside mx:Application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I  create some elements( UIComponents, mainly Panels) inside the “mx:Application name=”tst” “. I need to cleanup all those  UIComponent’s  on MouseClick event , using Actionscript. Is there any way I access the children elements of mx:Application ( I used 

        `var totalChildren:Number = this[‘tst’].numChildren ;` 

but looks like it fails to access the children list).
Thanks
Palash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application.application.removeAllChildren();

Comment: Hi 
I create those panel elements dynamically and add those to the Application ( core container) dynamically like the following:
<code>
this.rawChildren.addChild(panel);</code>
Then I try to cleanup the panels on click.  
Even if I use :
Application.application.removeAllChildren();- then also it cannot remove Panels.
Thanks
Palash

Comment: Hi
Instead of using this.rawChildren.addChild(panel), if I add panel's to Application (  Application.application.addChild(panel)), removing panels work(Application.application.removeAllChildren();). The issue is resolved.
Thanks for all your help.
Palash